# Strip first part of each line to colon

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

So I have a textfile of which I want to remove everything to the first colon (including the colon). So for example if this is the input

```
0000007ba9ec6950086ce79a8f3a389db4235830:9515rfsvk
000000da2a12da3fbe01a95bddb8ee183c62b94d:letmein2x
000000edf3179a1cf4c354471a897ab7f420bd52:heychudi:rbhai
000000f636f0d7cbc963a62f3a1bc87c9c985a04:cornetti
0000010a15f5b9315ef8e113f139fa413d1f2eb2:3648067PY128
```

Then this should be the output

```
9515rfsvk
letmein2x
heychudi:rbhai
cornetti
3648067PY128
```

Note that the second colon in line 3 remain, only from the start of each line to (including) the first column should be removed.

Is there a quick way to do this with grep or awk?

Comment: Not with grep but certainly with sed.

Comment: Yeah, I keep forgetting about -o and my knowledge of regexps predates perl :-)

Comment: @agc That is not a good duplicate target as there is only one `/` in the target.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With `cut`

```
cut -d: -f2- file
```

`-d` sets the separator and `-f2-` means from the second to the last field.

Comment: Thanks thats what I needed! :) What if I only want to keep the first part? EDIT: `-f1` is what I need for that, figured it out myself :D

Comment: @user4042470: exactly. and to keep from fields 2 to 4 including the 2 separators: `cut -d':' -f 2-4`

Answer (score 10):

With sed:

```
sed 's/[^:]*://' input.txt
```

In words: match a sequence of zero or more non-colon characters followed by a colon and replace them with nothing.

Answer (score 4):

This could work with `grep` (PCRE):

```
 grep -Po "(?<=:).*" file
```

Output:

```
9515rfsvk
letmein2x
heychudi:rbhai
cornetti
3648067PY128
```

Comment: Or `grep -oP ':\K.*'`

Answer (score 1):

With **bash** itself:

```
$ str=000000edf3179a1cf4c354471a897ab7f420bd52:heychudi:rbhai
$ echo "${str%%:*}"
000000edf3179a1cf4c354471a897ab7f420bd52
```

I found the bash-way extremely handy in all scripting work and it has replaced using `sed` in many occasions.

For more information about why this works, please look up in `man bash` EXPANSION > Parameter expansion.

Comment: To do that you need to also write a shell loop around it to read each line of the file, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score -2):

If the first `:` is always at position 41 in the file, you can use:

```
colrm 1 41 <file
```

or

```
cut -c42- file
```

Not the most convenient option since you need to first determine the position of the column, but at least it can also work in the absence of a separator.